# Change Regex to Get QueryString value in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, query-string

My function to get query string is:

```
GetID: function(name) {
    return decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]);
     },
```

And when I got a url:

```
http://localhost/testsite/testB.aspx?ID=12
```

and call this function Its return `12`.

But now my url pattern is change.

Current url pattern is:

```
  http://localhost/testsite/testB.aspx/12
```

Now I try to change regex and replace `?` with `/` and other things  to get desire value `12`.

But I am not success.My knowledge about `regex` is not so good so  help to modify my regex to get desire value.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Change the title of your question to something related to regular expressions then.

Comment: I want a help to change regex pattern bcz my url pattern is changed so how it duplicate? Given link only work when its has a common url not in special pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get number `12` in both url string:

```
var myStr = "http://localhost/testsite/testB.aspx/12";
```

or

```
var myStr = "http://localhost/testsite/testB.aspx?ID=12";
```

You just need to use only 1 regex:

```
var number = parseInt(myStr.match(/[0-9]+(?!.*[0-9])/), 10);
```

or simplier:

```
var number = parseInt(myStr.match(/\d+$/), 10);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RPjaq/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RPjaq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your previous regex simply didn't care for the `?` you are trying to replace by `/` (as I assume your *name* var contains *ID*).
Cannot do much with so few information about your URLs (you switched to get parameters to URL, they don't work the same way at all, what's the general form of your URLs?), but I'll give it a try:

```
/\d+$/
```

will simply get you the numbers at the end of your URL.